# Kentico Cache Dependencies

Tags: caching, content-management-system, kentico, outputcache

I'm having issues getting the Output Cache Dependencies webpart to work.
Here is my setup:

- Master page has 20m output cache
- All pages inherit this
- Master page contains a navigation webpart repeater

The custom data source caching works for the navigation repeater. I also placed an Output Cache Dependencies webpart on the master page with the following settings:

**Use Default Cache Dependencies: True

Cache Dependencies:**

```
nodes|mysite|NavigationItem|all
```

I would expect that making changes to a document type of NavigationItem would clear the output cache on the master page as the webpart is on the master page and all other pages inherit this master page but it seems I need to wait for the 20 minutes output cache to expire.

I have tried this with and without partial caching (using the same dependency keys). I also tried having no output cache on the navigation pages.

Is there something I'm missing or not understanding here?

**EDIT**
it seems it works when I use the partial cache on the navigation webpart after all

Comment: Yeah that's always a tricky part, on Repeaters there is the Partial Cache and the normal Cache.  Normal cache i believe will cache the data, the 2nd caches the output itself.  Your data may clear but the output won't, so you have to at least set the partial cache, possibly both but i think i usually only need the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for the presence of the cache dependency key you've specified? 
In Kentico 10, you can go to the "Debug" application, under "Cache Items", "Dummy Keys" and search for your document type.
https://www.screencast.com/t/vGEK8hkjdY

Edit a page, then search the dummy keys for "navigationitem" to see if anything shows up.

Most document types have a class prepended to them - I'm wondering if your cache dependency should read "nodes|mysite|cms.navigationitem|all" or something similar.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Incase anybody comes across this issue...

The output cache dependency (settings -> system -> performance) didn't have device profile and browser set, that was the issue.